# How to start a new activity when item is clicked of a custom list view

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to start new activity when I select an item of a custom list view, I tried the app on emulator and the new activity is not started and the item was not clickable...!. Why the item is not clickable ? any idea ? any suggestion ?

The following is the activity that uses a custom list view:

```
package com.example.welcome.madrasti;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListOfSchoolsPublic extends AppCompatActivity {

        Intent redirect;
        Intent item;
        ListView list;
        ArrayList<String>  _sa;
        DBAdapter db;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_schools_public);

            openDB();

            list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersList);

            redirect = getIntent();

            Cursor cursor = db.getAllRows();

            _sa= new  ArrayList<String>();

            //cursor.moveToFirst();

            Log.d("CURSORCOUNT","Number of rows in the Cursor is = " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));




            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

                if(cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_SChOOL_TYPE_TABLE_2).equals("حكومية"))
                _sa.add(cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_SCHOOLNAME_TABLE_2));

            }

            cursor.close();


            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,_sa);

            list.setAdapter(new TempLyaout(ListOfSchoolsPublic.this,_sa));


           list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
                {

                    String selectedItem = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    itemInfo(selectedItem);
                }
            });



    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void itemInfo(String selectedItem){

           item = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewSchool.class);

           item.putExtra("schoolName",selectedItem);

           startActivity(item);

    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        closeDB();

    }// end onDestroy method



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void openDB() {
        db = new DBAdapter(ListOfSchoolsPublic.this);
        db.open();
    } // end openDB method

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void closeDB() {
        db.close();
    } // end closeDB method

}
```

The following is the xml of the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListOfSchoolsPublic">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/usersList"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="523dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_x="4dp"
        android:layout_y="-1dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp"></ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why you are using  
            
            list.setAdapter(new TempLyaout(ListOfSchoolsPublic.this,_sa); instead of list.setAdapter(adaptor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue presist when you have some clickable item in your list item.

If your item listener is not working then you can apply this on ListView in xml layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

You can also put many clicks listeners if you need in adapter class like

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
        Context context;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> users) {
            super(context, 0, users);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Contact user = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listviewadapter, parent, false);
            }
            TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView num = convertView.findViewById(R.id.num);
            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object

            name.setText(user.name);
            num.setText(user.phone_number);
            // can set click on name or num
            name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, position + "position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            // can set click on full list item
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, position + "position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```